# Stripping LIKE result to it's own column

Tags: sql, oracle

In my SQL I am looking for items that I am search for using the LIKE command.  Is there a way to determine which LIKE was found on each row of data?

```
SELECT DISTINCT VICSEC.VSID, VICSEC.VSDESCRIPTION
FROM VSUSER.VICSEC INNER JOIN VSUSER.VSNOTES ON VICSEC.VSID=VSNOTES.VSID
WHERE VICSEC.VSSHIPDATE between sysdate and (sysdate+14)
AND(UPPER(VICSEC.VSDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%***GARTER***%'
OR UPPER(VICSEC.VSDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%DEMIBRA%'
OR UPPER(VICSEC.VSDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%PANTY%'
OR UPPER(VICSEC.VSDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%PAJAMA%'
OR UPPER(VICNOTES.VSNOTE) LIKE '%***GARTER***%'
OR UPPER(VICNOTES.VSNOTE) LIKE '%DEMIBRA%'
OR UPPER(VICNOTES.VSNOTE) LIKE '%PANTY%'
OR UPPER(VICNOTES.VSNOTE) LIKE '%PAJAMA%'
OR UPPER(VICSEC.VSSTORITEM) LIKE '%***GARTER***%'
OR UPPER(VICSEC.VSSTORITEM) LIKE '%DEMIBRA%'
OR UPPER(VICSEC.VSSTORITEM) LIKE '%PANTY%'
OR UPPER(VICSEC.VSSTORITEM) LIKE '%PAJAMA%')
ORDER BY VICSEC.VSID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` expressions for this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN UPPER(VICSEC.VSDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%***GARTER***%' THEN 1 else 0 END as GARTER,
  CASE WHEN UPPER(VICSEC.VSDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%DEMIBRA%' THEN 1 else 0 END as DEMIBRA,
```

etc...

If you are looking for anything that found one of them, you can use multiple expressions in your WHEN clause, since it just takes an expression as the argument.

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(VICSEC.VSDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%DEMIBRA%' 
          OR UPPER(VICNOTES.VSNOTE) LIKE '%DEMIBRA%'  
     THEN 1 else 0 END as DEMIBRA,
```

Comment: Can it be done where the results are in one field instead of a field for each item?  We have hundreds/thousands of items.

Comment: What do you mean by results? Like an aggregate? You can do a `GROUP BY` to group by the columns you want and use `COUNT` or `SUM` to get aggregated values..